# Is it possible to determine, whether current code output is being buffered in PHP?

Tags: php, ob-start

Is there a method to determine, whether the echo/print in a random place in a file is being buffered with `ob_start`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ob_get_level()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php) will return the current output buffering level (the number of output buffers active, since you can call `ob_start()` multiple times in a row), so a return value of 0 means no output buffering is active

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ob_get_level()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php) function:

```
<?php
if(ob_get_level() > 0) { 
    // output buffering active
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is...

See [`ob_get_level()`](http://us.php.net/ob_get_level):

```
if (ob_get_level() > 0) {
    //Output Buffering Is Active!
}
```

But be sure to read the comments on that page for insight as to what's going on, as certain `php.ini` settings can set a output buffer from before the start of the script...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ob_get_clean()` to see what's hiding inside that buffer.

Comment: You probably meant `ob_get_contents()`, since `ob_get_clean()` would erase the buffer

Comment: No because then he could spit out the buffer whenever he needed to see what was in that specific code span. ob_get_contents stacks on itself so he could do multiple ob_get_clean's on a page and each would be unique.